# How to handle things when a user openly admits they are using pirated software?

Tags: discussion

I removed the last sentence of this question where the user states "I'm using a cracked version."

[I cant find a saved symbols or graphic styles when i start to work on a new file. how to fix this problem?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/156078/i-cant-find-a-saved-symbols-or-graphic-styles-when-i-start-to-work-on-a-new-file)

For me, it's troublesome to ask *paying* customers for help while explaining you've stolen what they paid for. Which, in turn, drives up the prices they pay due to your theft.

I don't *want* to help if you are using stolen software.

On the other hand, ignorance is bliss, and had I *not* known the user stole the software I'd be happy to help and not concern myself with the legal issues of whether or not their software is legit.

Does openly stating you've stolen the software completely negate any question related to that software?

I'm *not* passing any moral judgement to be clear. Simply put... I pay more because of software piracy. So.. assisting someone who pirates the software is against my own interests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't tell you how your personal ethics and morals should work. If you feel uncomfortable aiding a user who admits to doing something against you personal code, by all means ignore them. Or even tell them as much, respectfully.

I don't think you are **assisting** a user pirate software if you answer them about the *use* of the software. As you said, the way software was obtained has no impact on it's use. If you had not known, there would not have been any issue.

So all in all, it is a personal choice.

---

<sub>I know you know this @Scott, but just a reminder for newer users:</sub>

It is *not allowed* on SE to aid people in pirating software or doing similar illegal stuff. If you encounter users exchanging keys, posting illegal torrents, etc, please *flag for moderator attention*. This is content that needs to be removed immediately.